# how to trigger a button click in my code?

Tags: c#, windows-8

How can I trigger a button click directly in my code?

I have a code like this:

```
namespace App1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            // fire a click ebent von the "Button" MyBtn
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to fire a click event von the button `MyBtn`? If yes how?

I know I can call the `Button_Click` method, but I want to call it over the button.

something like: `MyBtn.FireClickEvent();`

Comment: Really don't understand this requirement, if you need to execute the code in button_click extract it in a separate method and call from button_click event handler and from wherever you need

Comment: Its a very long description why I need to do it. If it is not possible post it or show me a way how to do it.

Comment: A sure sign of an overly (and unnecessarily) complicated design is when someone says *sorry, too complicated to explain why I need to do this thing*...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can trigger the `Button_Click` event from the code as follows:

```
MyBtn.PerformClick();
```

You can try this one also:

```
MyBtn.Click(new object(), new EventArgs());
```

Comment: The button in a Win Store app does not have this method.

Comment: this line of code `MyBtn.Click(new object(), new EventArgs());`is wrong in so many different ways. 1. It does not trigger the event, it just calls the method. 2. don't create a new object, sender should always be the object itself (MyBtn) 3. Don't use new EventArgs but `EventArgs.Empty` 4. If you really don't want to trigger the event but execute the same method a button triggers from your code, you should make the click eventhandler call another method. From your own code just call the same method.

Answer (score 2):

**You can remove the method link to your event(Click) :**

```
MyBtn.Click -= new EventHandler(Button_Click);
```

**And add an other method :**

```
MyBtn.Click += new EventHandler(FireClickEvent);
```

So, when you will click the button, the method "FireClickEvent" will be called instead of "Button_Click".

**To perform a click in the code :**

```
MyBtn.PerformClick();
```

Comment: Yep, you can - and you shouldn't. Two reasons: (1) Specifying what should happen by what gets clicked only leads to less clear code and (slightly) harder-to-change UI. (2) PerformClick just raises the Click event, and thus is just an inefficient way of invoking the method.

Comment: The button in a Win Store app does not have this method.

Answer (score 0):

I use this little extension to fire events from outside.
It is kind of generic (can raise any event in any class) but I put it as a extension method to control only, since this is bad practice and I realy realy use it only if everything else fails. Have fun.

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{

    public static void SimulateClick(this Control c)
    {
        c.RaiseEvent("Click", EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public static void RaiseEvent(this Control c, string eventName, EventArgs e)
    {

        // TO simulate the delegate invocation we obtain it's invocation list
        // and walk it, invoking each item in the list
        Type t = c.GetType();
        FieldInfo fi = t.GetField(eventName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        MulticastDelegate d = fi.GetValue(c) as MulticastDelegate;
        Delegate[] list = d.GetInvocationList();

        // It is important to cast each member to an appropriate delegate type
        // For example for the KeyDown event we would replace EventHandler
        // with KeyEvenHandler and new EventArgs() with new KeyHandlerEventArgs()
        foreach (EventHandler del in list)
        {
            del.Invoke(c, e);
        }

    }

}
```