# Call DeleteButtonClick with Delete button from keyboard

Tags: c#, keyboard-shortcuts

```
private void BrisiBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (tabelaIsplakaci.CurrentCell != null)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Дали сакате да го избришите овој запис? ", "Избриши запис", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            cIsplakciPrimaci currentIsplakac = lstIsplakaci[tabelaIsplakaci.CurrentCell.RowIndex];
            IPDB.DeleteIsplakac(currentIsplakac, ZiroSmetkaObj);
            MessageBox.Show("Записот е избришан!");
            tabelaIsplakaci.Rows.RemoveAt(tabelaIsplakaci.CurrentCell.RowIndex);
            ReadIsplakaci();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Записот не е избришан! ", "Избриши запис", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
    else { MessageBox.Show("Не постои ниеден запис!"); }
}
```

I have this button to delete data, and i need to call it with Delete button 
from keyboard, so I do this:

```
private void Isplakaci_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
    {
        //what should I do here, if I write
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to trigger a button click in my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16792160/how-to-trigger-a-button-click-in-my-code)

Comment: thank you i was searching i didn`t found, but now i`ve seen it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't pretend to understand the language you're using nor to reconstruct all of your code, I can offer you an example that you should be able to change to get working.

The thing you want to avoid is in any way trying to simulate a click. You want to separate out your logic away from the UI as much as possible. This is the kind of structure you need:

```
private void BrisiBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (tabelaIsplakaci.CurrentCell != null)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Дали сакате да го избришите овој запис? ", "Избриши запис", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            cIsplakciPrimaci currentIsplakac = lstIsplakaci[tabelaIsplakaci.CurrentCell.RowIndex];
            DeleteIsplakaci(currentIsplakac);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Записот не е избришан! ", "Избриши запис", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
    else { MessageBox.Show("Не постои ниеден запис!"); }
}

private void Isplakaci_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
    {
        DeleteIsplakaci(currentIsplakac);
    }
}

private void DeleteIsplakaci(cIsplakciPrimaci currentIsplakac)
{
    IPDB.DeleteIsplakac(currentIsplakac, ZiroSmetkaObj);
    MessageBox.Show("Записот е избришан!");
    tabelaIsplakaci.Rows.RemoveAt(tabelaIsplakaci.CurrentCell.RowIndex);
    ReadIsplakaci();
}
```

I know that this code will not work as is - you need to refactor - but the structure should be fairly well right.

Comment: I`m new so this is my first project, so i make a lot of mistakes, but i`m thankful for comments and answers like this because they help me a lot now and i`m sure in future. Thanks again for the great answer.

Answer (score -1):

I would not recommend to perform button click. Because it is logically incorrect. Try to make explicit procedure ( at least a `function` with or without parameters) to put your logic and explicitly call this procedure in any place you want this functionality (including button click event). This will be more appropriate and readable.
 But if you want to 
you can use [PerformClick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick(v=vs.110).aspx) on button.

> Example

```
BrisiBtn.PerformClick();
```

Comment: While I agree that this method works, it's not the best for encouraging good programming style. This encourages entangling business logic with UI and back to business logic. It's better to bypass the UI entirely and just call a business function. Code inside `BrisiBtn_Click` and `Isplakaci_KeyDown` should both call a common business logic method.

Comment: I agree with you. But they asked and got what they wanted

Comment: @Elbek - Yes, I understand. What you should do is explain in your answer why you would not recommend this approach. Otherwise it comes across as saying "I don't recommend what I'm recommending". That's confusing for future readers.